# How to make Users automatically Follow Admin User on Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin, twitter-follow

Currently I allow users to follow one another on my rails app **(similar to twitter)**.

**I would love if New Users that sign up to the site Automatically follow Admin User.**

```
Similar to how MySpace use to automatically make Tom your first friend
```

Below is the code I use to create new users and allow users to follow one another.(i know this is a very broad question but .....)

**(Can someone please point me in the right direction onto how I can get this started. Would I need to create a method....in my models or add code to the controller?)**

New to Rails Please help)... :)

**USER CONTROLLER**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: [:destroy]

  respond_to :html, :js

  def new
    @user = RegularUser.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 100).search(params[:search])
  end

  def destroy
    User.find_by_username(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def create
    @user = RegularUser.new(params[:regular_user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      UserMailer.welcome_user(@user).deliver
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the ClickOnComics!"
      redirect_to (publishers_path)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def follow_admins
      admins = User.find_by_admin(true)
      admins.each do |admin|
      self.follow!(admin)
    end
end

class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :current_user

  respond_to :html, :js

 def create
   @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
   respond_with @user
 end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_with @user
  end

end
```

**MODELS**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               class_name:  "Relationship",
                               dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  after_create :follow_admins

  def follow_admins
    admins = User.find_all_by_admin(true)
      admins.each do |admin|
      self.follow!(admin)
    end
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end

end
```

**I used this tutorial to help me establish privileged administrative users with a boolean admin attribute in the User model**

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-administrative_users

**SCHEMA**

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.string    "email"
    t.string    "role"
    t.string    "username"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                                :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                                :null => false
    t.boolean   "admin",                  :default => false
    t.string    "password_reset_token"
    t.timestamp "password_reset_sent_at"
  end
```

**Would I need to create a Method that defines user_admin?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user.rb add a after_create filter

```
after_create :follow_admin!

def follow_admin!
  relationships.create!(followed_id: admin_user.id)
end
```

Comment: I have added some code above to explain how I've established admin privileges. i get this error when i added the code to the user.rb (undefined local variable or method `admin_user') Would i need to create a method that defines admin_user?

Answer (score 1):

In `create` action before `sign_in` add

```
@user.follow! admin_user
```

you need to fetch admin user first somehow.
Good idea would be to make `follow!`, `following?` and `unfollow!` methods to accept either id or object as in

```
def follow!(user_or_id)
  id = (user_or_id.is_a?(User) ? user_or_id.id : user_or_id)
  relationships.create!(followed_id: id)
end
```

Comment: you need to define method `admin?` on User class, which will basically just check admin attribute so `def admin?; self.admin; end`

Comment: But when you users to follow admin have in mind that in some future you may have multiple admin accounts, so be prepared to handle that case!

Comment: Surge, you need a way to identify user as an admin and to get all admins. My code doesn't need to change, but you need to figure out how your app wants. (if there will be multiple admin you'd call `@user.follow! admin_user` couple of times, that's it.

Comment: okay, i think i understand what your saying. Lastly, would the fact that i already have a private method admin_user in my user controller that i use as a before_action change anything....because the error (undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass) is actually pointing me to that method.

Comment: Surge, I gave `admin_user` as an example, a PLACEHOLDER. Change it if you need to! Also I don't know if rails does `?` methods for bools - if it does, great.

Comment: 1. How you expect `@user.follow! follow_admins` to work if argument is a method which calls `follow!` by itself. You should just call`follow_admins`!

Comment: 2. What does this return `User.find_by_admin(true)` I think error comes from here

Comment: Yea you are correct it was that....I also decided to change the code and put it in the model as mentioned below. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Man, but I am not gonna teach you programming in SO comments. Try things out, if you don't understand something READ, READ and even READ more. That's the way to become great programmer, you can do it!

Comment: lol. kk well thanks for all your help. really appreciate it :)