# railstutorial.org - make new users follow admin users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I've followed Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial making an app like Twitter and I want to change it so that all new users to automatically 'follow' the Admin/s.

I've tried to do it following answers to similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758961/how-to-make-users-automatically-follow-admin-user-on-sign-up) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803049/how-can-i-make-user-follow-all-admin-users-at-signup), but they throw errors on account creation.  Here's the relevant section of my user controller.

*Edit: `find_all_by_admin` is deprecated in Rails 4.2.0 as explained in the selected answer by Vinay.*

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...

  def follow_admins
    admins = User.find_all_by_admin(true) # EDIT - Deprecated: May have worked prior to rails 4.2
    admins.each do |admin|
      self.follow!(admin)
    end
  end
```

The error message is

**NoMethodError in UsersController#create**

> undefined method `find_all_by_admin' for #

Comment: You never defined `find_all_by_admins`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that there is **`no column`** with **`admin`** name in your **`User model`** as we might can see [Michael Hartl's sample_app_3rd_edition](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition/blob/master/db/schema.rb#l45)

So in order to make `follow_admins` method work you need to **add admin column in users table type boolean and default: false**.

```
  def follow_admins
    admins = User.find_all_by_admin(true) # would be worked in rails 4.0 not rails 4.2.2
    admins = User.where(admin: true) # Should be work in rails 4.2.2
    # Most of the Dynamic finder has been removed form rails 4.2.2
    admins.each do |admin|
      self.follow!(admin)
    end
  end
```

**note** As I mention in my answer `default to false` ,It is not mandatory but as you are following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial It good to go accordingly .

hope this answer would help you !!!

Comment: Hey @Vinay I just had to go out for a while.  Thanks for your response, I'll check it out shortly (after tea).

Comment: I just checked my schema and it already contains `t.boolean  "admin",             default: false`

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.0

Comment: Great catch, mate!! :)

Comment: That has stopped the error and allowed users to register now, but somehow the new user still doesn't follow the admins.

Comment: @Well I answer your exact question and  that thing you need to sort out.

Comment: You were a great help!  Yeah, I think I know what I messed up while trying to fix things.  All is good. :)

Comment: I don't know why people down voted my question.  It was detailed enough and deprecated code can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you never defined the `find_all_by_admin` method in the `User` model.

Open the `User` model file and check if the method is there. If not, define it as a class method.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer shouldn't it?

Comment: @Ekult3k why should it be a comment? This is the answer to why the user is getting that error message.